# mod_rewrite image problems

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ /type1/internal.php?parentFolders=$1&pageTitleID=$2 [L]
```

When I visit `http://localhost/type1/page/home/play` it works fine, however I would like to take the `/page/` out therefore being `http://localhost/type1/home/play`

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /type1/internal.php?parentFolders=$1&pageTitleID=$2 [L]
```

however some images seem to vanish, and some don't.

Also, I find hard links in my nav do not work either as they are asking for variables used in internal pages.

I am not sure if this is a absolute/relative problem as my CSS is written as

```
<link href="http://localhost/type1/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and links seem to be full links when I inspect them with my browser!?

Any help would be great

Comment: sorry i have just looked at my question again today... was pretty tired last night when i wrote this... i would like the url to be http://localhost/type1/home/play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the .htaccess file is located in `/type1/` subfolder. Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /type1/internal.php?parentFolders=$1&pageTitleID=$2 [L,QSA]
```

1. The `(.*)` pattern you are using is too broad for first parameter, I use `([^/]+)` instead (any character except slash).
2. Added 2 rewrite conditions .. so only requests to non-existing files and folders will be rewritten. This should help with disappeared images (or may not -- it all depends how how the links are written).
3. Added `QSA` flag to preserve any existing query string.

Comment: LazyOne you are god in web development format!!! thanks so much! I have been busting my b's for a while on this now!... all works but the new ([^/]+). The parentFolders value is similar to "/home/blog/article1" e.g. the url of the web page (excluding //localhost/ etc. The cms creates this to put in for links and so on... also helps for things such as bread crumbs and dynamic title tags... i have replaced that with ([^*]+) is that ok, or is there a better way of doing it?     Once again thanks so much!

Comment: @Theo `([^/]+)` means "at lest one ANY character, but not slash `/`". This is perfect pattern for separating path segments, as it will ALWAYS match only ONE segment, while `(.*)` means "ZERO or more of ANY characters". Also consider: This pattern `^(.*)/(.*)$` will match `help/delivery` as well as `help/pink/kitten` as well as `help/me/please/anyone`. If that is OK for you -- they use your original pattern `(.*)` as `([^*]+)` does not make much sense.

Comment: Ok great stuff! essentially I use the parentFolders value for other things, as said before, breadcrubs etc. All information on the page is pulled bassed on the pageTitleID, so if somoene puts /this/is/some/random/text/page-number-1, it wont matter as long as the pageTitleID is pulled through e.g page content is $pageTitleID['pageContent'], or $pageTitleID['internalImage'].   Would you say that this is an ok way of formating my cms? Do you think it will be ok from and SEO point of view?

Comment: @Theo If you want some authoritative answer, better ask it at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (a sister site of StackOverflow). But if you ask me -- I do not really like such approach (variable length path with ID at the end): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17002/why-does-stackoverflow-question-urls-have-the-question-id-before-seo-friendly-qu/17052#17052 **P.S.** If you find my answer useful, please consider marking it as accepted (if it solves your issue, of course).

Comment: Nice one! Thanks a lot LazyOne you have been a great help to me! Much appreciated!